# How to detect trigger method call event in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to detect triggered click event in javascript, my code is

```
$(".my_button").click(function(){

    // if event fired form .trigger() method from other method or event then do something

    // actuall code for click event is here
})

.....
.....

$('.other_first_button').click(function(){
    // code of other first button
    $(".my_button").trigger('click');
});

.....
.....

$('.other_second_button').click(function(){
    // code of other second button
    $(".my_button").trigger('click');
});
```

**Note:** I want to identify click event call using jquery `trigger()` method in `$(".my_button").click()`.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You can pass extra data to event handler, see [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: I gotcha, thanks @A.Wolff

Comment: Note that you could check for `event.isTrigger` but this isn't publibly supported: https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/319  (EDIT: btw there main developper suggests to check for `event.originalEvent` but imho better is to explecitely handling it, passing parameter to event handler while using `$.fn.trigger()` method)  https://jsfiddle.net/vk1e3sp0/1

Comment: @Samir, please read my question properly.

Comment: @Samir this won't let you check if user click on this element or if this click event was triggered by the click on other element, and that's all the question

Comment: @Samir, I have already mentioned as Note:.. no worries :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a parameter to the trigger click event as

```
$(".my_button").trigger('click', ['btn2']);
```

Recieve it in click event on my button as

```
$(".my_button").click(function(e, p2){
```

Not check if p2 is undefined or has some value, if it has it has been triggered using a `trigger()` event

```js
$(".my_button").click(function(e, p1){

    // if event fired form .trigger() method from other method or event then do something
    if(p1 != undefined)
 alert('triggered from ' + p1);
    // actuall code for click event is here
})


$('.other_first_button').click(function(){
    // code of other first button
    $(".my_button").trigger('click', ['btn1']);
});


$('.other_second_button').click(function(){
    // code of other second button
    $(".my_button").trigger('click', ['btn2']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="other_first_button">
First
</button>
<button class="other_second_button">
Second
</button>
<button class="my_button">
mybtn
</button>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/1s6sp6x5/)

Comment: Thanks... in `$('.my_button').click(function(p1,p2){...})` then `p1` is stands for? and `p2` is always array or every separate parameter?

Comment: Good that you edited the code its clearer now. p1 was the event parameter and p2 was the custom sent parameter and yes happy to help